# Issues while installing Python 3.6 on Windows 7 : Service Pack 1 is required to continue installation

Tags: python, windows-7, python-3.6

I am unable to install Python 3.6 on Windows 7 Professional Edition 32 bits the install dialog points me to the log file whose content is as follows:

```
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i001: Burn v3.10.3.3007, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\sos\AppData\Local\Temp\{948239C0-AFB0-400B-8609-44F78A4DD47A}\.cr\python-3.6.5.exe
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'ActionLikeInstalling' to value 'Installing'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'ShortVersion' to value '3.6'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'ShortVersionNoDot' to value '36'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'WinVer' to value '3.6-32'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'WinVerNoDot' to value '36-32'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallAllUsers' to value '0'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallLauncherAllUsers' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDir' to value ''
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultAllUsersTargetDir' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]Python[WinVerNoDot]'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetPlatform' to value 'x86'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultJustForMeTargetDir' to value '[LocalAppDataFolder]Programs\Python\Python[WinVerNoDot]'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'OptionalFeaturesRegistryKey' to value 'Software\Python\PythonCore\[WinVer]\InstalledFeatures'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDirRegistryKey' to value 'Software\Python\PythonCore\[WinVer]\InstallPath'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultCustomTargetDir' to value ''
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'CustomInstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value '[InstallLauncherAllUsersState]'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDirState' to value 'enabled'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'CustomBrowseButtonState' to value 'enabled'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_core' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_exe' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_dev' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_lib' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_test' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_doc' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_tools' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_tcltk' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_pip' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_launcher' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'Include_launcherState' to value 'enabled'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_symbols' to value '0'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_debug' to value '0'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'LauncherOnly' to value '0'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'DetectedLauncher' to value '0'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'DetectedOldLauncher' to value '0'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'AssociateFiles' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Shortcuts' to value '1'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'PrependPath' to value '0'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'CompileAll' to value '0'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'SimpleInstall' to value '0'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'SimpleInstallDescription' to value ''
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\sos\Downloads\python-3.6.5.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=160 -burn.filehandle.self=168'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\sos\Downloads\python-3.6.5.exe'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\sos\Downloads\'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\sos\AppData\Local\Temp\Python 3.6.5 (32-bit)_20180530011525.log'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Python 3.6.5 (32-bit)'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Python Software Foundation'
[1398:1318][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Setting numeric variable 'CRTInstalled' to value 0
[1398:0874][2018-05-30T01:15:25]i000: Did not find C:\Users\sos\Downloads\unattend.xml
[1398:0874][2018-05-30T01:15:26]i000: Setting string variable 'ActionLikeInstalling' to value 'Installing'
[1398:0874][2018-05-30T01:15:26]i000: Setting string variable 'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'
[1398:0874][2018-05-30T01:15:26]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '3.6.5150.0'
[1398:0874][2018-05-30T01:15:26]e000: Detected Windows 7 RTM
[1398:0874][2018-05-30T01:15:26]e000: Service Pack 1 is required to continue installation
```

How can I solve this error ? Should I install a different version of Windows in order to make this work ?

Answer (score 3):

Check the last line:

```
[1398:0874][2018-05-30T01:15:26]e000: Service Pack 1 is required to continue installation
```

Why don't you just install Service Pack 1?
Here is the download link. https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=5842

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must have to install Service Pack 1 in order to make it installed.
or you have to continue your stuff with Python 2.7.

Download Service Pack 1 from the link suggested by @jerrycheng

Answer (score 0):

Well, I faced the same issue while downloading and installing python 3.7.7 from the official website. But, soon I realized the Anaconda environment lets you update python easily without much effort.

If you have Anaconda preinstalled, then on cmd prompt, enter: `conda update python` which will update your existing version of python. I was able to update my python from 3.7.0 to 3.7.7.

[You can download Anaconda from the official website](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual)

Comment: This is not a problem in this particular case. That doesn't matter if you're installing Python on Anaconda or not. Read the last two lines of the log to understand what I mean.